# VBA script in word -- trying to replace a figure in a table cell

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the below table in word that I'm trying to write a script to replace the contents of the below cell with a different customer payment (i.e replace the £1,100 with £2,000). Below is a snippet of my script but the when i write back to the cell it loses all the formatting and the numbered list.

Thank you for your help in advance

ps.I've simplified the contents of the cell to make it easier to read, so the code won't apply to exactly that content

```
DescPlan = Trim(t1.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text)

DescTest = InStr(1, DescPlan, "below:")

finalString = Left(DescPlan, Len(DescPlan) - DescTest - 14)

t1.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = Replace(DescPlan, finalString, "Payment by the customer of " + Format(v, "Currency") + " will be due upon completion of items below:" + vbCrLf)
```

[Screenshot of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9iBm.png)

[After running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRhUm.png)

Comment: You will want to write to the `.Value` or `.Value2` property instead of the `.Text` property of the cell. That should preserve the formatting.